# Error unable to access jarfile C:\Jar

Tags: java, command-line

My jar file P2.jar (which has a main method and manifest file) is located in `C:\Jar Folder`. I tried to run it from cmd like this:

`C:SomeRandomFolder> java -jar C:\Jar Folder\P2.jar`

I get the error:

```
unable to access jarfile C:\Jar
```

It works when I run it from the folder that the jar is in like this:

```
C:\Jar Folder> java -jar P2.jar
```

Why can't I use the 1st command? Why do I have to go to the directory of my jar file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's because of the space you have in the path name. On Windows, use quotes:

`java -jar "C:\Jar Folder\P2.jar"`

Comment: Note: Parameters passed to jar file should not be included in quotes. Ex: java -jar "path with spaces\jarfile" foo bar

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I have the exact same problem without the spaces in the path name and with/without quotes.

Comment: @SomJura it solved the op's issue, and possibly many others'. There could be other reasons. You're welcome to post your findings and we'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a terminal and the folder you are in is deleted out from underneath you and replaced with the same content, the jar file will be be visible with `ls`, but will not be available since your current directory was deleted and replaced with one that looks just like it.

I got that error too:

```
el@apollo:/myproject/build/jar$ java -jar CalculateStats.jar
Unable to access jarfile CalculateStats.jar
```

To fix it.  `cd` up a directory and `cd` back in, like this:

```
el@apollo:/myproject/build/jar$ cd ..
el@apollo:/myproject/build$ cd jar/
el@apollo:/myproject/build/jar$ java -jar CalculateStats.jar
Program completed successfully
```